# UICollectionView Inside of UITableViewCell: Crashing in iPhone 6S Plus

Tags: iphone, uitableview, swift2, uicollectionview, xcode7

The Following is not Running Perfectly in iPhone 6S Plus.
Runs in iPhone 5s as Expected.
Its Just A sample Code.It is also having same issue.

Rows:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{

    return 5
}
```

Contents :  5 cells

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var RetCell = UITableViewCell()

        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            let cell = self.HomeTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Banner" ,forIndexPath: indexPath)

            RetCell = cell

        }

        else if(indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            let cell = self.HomeTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Offer",forIndexPath: indexPath)

            RetCell = cell

        }
        else if(indexPath.row == 3)
        {
            let cell = self.HomeTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Category",forIndexPath: indexPath)

            RetCell = cell

        }
        else if(indexPath.row == 2)
        {

            let cell = self.HomeTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Products",forIndexPath: indexPath)

            RetCell = cell


        }
        else if(indexPath.row == 4)
        {
            let cell = self.HomeTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Recent",forIndexPath: indexPath)  

            RetCell = cell


        }

    return RetCell
}
```

Display Cell :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print(indexPath.row)

    if(indexPath.row == 2){
            guard let tableViewCell = cell as? ProductsTableViewCell else { return }

            tableViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)

    }

        if(indexPath.row == 4){
            guard let tableViewCell = cell as? RecentViewsTableViewCell else { return }

            tableViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)
        }

}
```

Extension For Same Class:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{


    let cellColl = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ProductCollection", forIndexPath: indexPath)




    return cellColl
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return 5
}
```

In TableViewCells : ProductsTableViewCell and Other Cell Contain following code in Extension

```
func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate<D: protocol<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>>(dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row: Int) {

    CollectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
    CollectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
    CollectionView.tag = row
    CollectionView.setContentOffset(CollectionView.contentOffset, animated:false) // Stops collection view if it was scrolling.
    CollectionView.reloadData()
}

var collectionViewOffset: CGFloat {
    set {
        CollectionView.contentOffset.x = newValue
    }

    get {
        return CollectionView.contentOffset.x
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the crash message?

Comment: reason: '-[UIView collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe98852a070'

Comment: I'd start by investigating the parameters passed to `setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate:`. The error suggests that you're setting the collection view datasource to a class that doesn't implement the mandatory `UICollectionViewDataSource` protocol methods.

Comment: But its running perfectly in iPhone 5s simulator. Crashing in 6s Plus.